# Are there any tabbed navigation plugins or gems you would recommend for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

I am going to develop a Rails application and the designer wants to include tabs as part of the interface / navigation (probably it will included nested tabs).

Are there any places you would recommend I look, as I guess this has all been done before.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at this collection of
[widgets](http://wiki.github.com/paolodona/rails-widgets) you can put in your Ruby On Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the [tabulous gem](https://github.com/techiferous/tabulous) just for this purpose.